How to sync Angular input with signal store without using effect
Say I have a simple UserStore signal store with that simple state:
{ username: string }

Now I created one component UserComponent using that store, and this component has a signal  input:
readonly #store = inject(UserStore);
username = input.required<string>();

What's the correct way to update my signal store when the component input value changes?
So far I am using an effect:
constructor() {
  effect(
    () => {
      const username = this.username();
      this.#store.setUsername(username);
    },
    { allowSignalWrites: true }
  );
}

But looking at the angular docs, I do think that using an effect is to be avoided.
Should I instead rely on the @Input annotation?
@Input({ required: true })
  set username(value: string) {
  this.#store.setUsername(value);
}


I would personally use ngOnChanges as a solution. With the set input function, you would need to create a variable like #_username and validate whether the variable has actually changed or not. Otherwise, you could end up in a loop or trigger the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked error. But I wonder, couldn't the parent component update its signal? This way, you would avoid having an input 'username' in your component and instead receive the signal directly in a computed property, making your component more independent and clean.

Same thought here. The parent should be handling calls to setUsername and the child's input should just be receiving the value.

The allowSignalWrites is going to be deprecated in the future, so you change the code to use untracked, which:

Execute an arbitrary function in a non-reactive (non-tracking) context. The executed function can, optionally, return a value.

So the effect will not detect the signal updates you make inside the untracked function.
The is a valid use case of effect. Just updating signals inside effect is frowned upon because it causes and error saying "You cannot update signals inside an effect", which does not happen when you use untracked.
constructor() {
  effect(
    () => {
      const username = this.username();
      untracked(() => { 
        this.#store.setUsername(username);
      });
    });
}

